# ABPersonViewController PerformDefaultAction problem

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

when i click a phone number record on the person view nothing happen for the HandlePvcPerformDefaultAction method. what should i do more? i just want to get selected phone number from this view.

```
ABPersonViewController pvc;
.....
pvc.DisplayedPerson = e.Person;
pvc.AllowsEditing = false;
pvc.PerformDefaultAction += HandlePvcPerformDefaultAction;

this.PresentModalViewController (pvc, true);
......
void HandlePvcPerformDefaultAction (object sender, ABPersonViewPerformDefaultActionEventArgs e)
{
   Console.WriteLine("HandlePvcPerformDefaultAction");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that in Objective-C the corresponding method for HandlePvcPerformDefaultAction returns a BOOL (as in: Should you perform the default action for the selected element?).

So I think you should change the return type to bool and return true.